# Java heap memory analysis with visualvm and MAT

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory, visualvm, heap-dump

I have a application running and recently noticed that my container not responding and behaving differently like logs not written or etc...

So i thought of collectin gth heap dump and analysing what is happening.

I chose VisualVM and MAT. While analysing i am getting confused now.

Please find the images below and would be great if i get some thoughts.

MAT shows report as normal, but shall heap size is more. Do we need to consider shallow heap size for crash. Could not find much info on shallo heap.

And Visualvm shows full memory.

**VISUALVM**

[image]

**MAT with unreachable_objects**

[image]

**MAT HISTOGRAM**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect the SSL engine classes to hog this much memory unless there's a massive amount of concurrent SSL connections. Something fishy is going on there.

Your options:

1. Try another (newer) JVM (might be a memory leak in there)
2. Check for open connections / adjust connection pool parameters to have stale connections dropped
3. Investigate further into these classes (SSLEngineResult, SSLEngineArgs)

If you need more help, be sure to add info about the type of load the application is seeing, which container you are using, and JVM version.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I am using apache karaf:3.0.0, jetty:8.x, openjdk:1.7.0_79.

Comment: Can you try an Oracle JDK and see if it changes anything? 
Also, regarding the actual load on your application: Do you have any custom configuration regarding threads/acceptors in your jetty.xml that would allow a high number of concurrent connections? (maybe post jetty.xml) How many requests does the server see in a given amount of time / how long does it take after a restart for your troubles to start?

Comment: Issue was with other java code https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/171 . Thank you.